# How do I fix Excel instability after using PowerQuery?

Tags: microsoft-excel, crash, office365, power-query, microsoft-excel-365

I've been working on some VBA code to import and parse PDF files using PowerQuery. The code itself is working fine, but after some column-related errors (I had more columns defined than some of the PDF files had) during development, every time I open a file in Excel it crashes within 5-20 seconds.

I know it's PowerQuery because the exact same thing happened on another workstation (first workstation is a Windows 10 Citrix virtual desktop, second is a Windows 10 laptop). However, on that one I was able to fix it by installing an Azure Information Protection update (I can't say exactly what it was because our corporate software portal is very vague, but it looked like it installed or updated an Excel Azure plugin). Needless to say, that didn't work on the original workstation.

It happens in Safe mode, it happens in Protected mode, it happens on every kind of Excel file including .csvs and blank workbooks, and it crashes Outlook if I open an Excel attachment in preview mode. The only scenarios where it doesn't crash are:

- New blank workbook
- Workbook opened from a template
- Workbook opened from Downloads and My Documents when they're defined as Trusted Locations (workbooks opened from subfolders still crash, even with subfolders checkbox in Trusted Locations; workbooks opened from other Trusted Locations also crash).

What I've tried so far (that I can remember):

- Disabled graphics acceleration
- Deleted contents of %TEMP% folder
- Deleted contents of %APPDATA%\Excel folder
- Deleted PowerQuery folder in AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0
- Repaired Office 365
- Reinstalled Office 365
- Updated Office 365 from version 2302 to 2309 (that's as high as I can go currently)
- Enabled network Trusted Locations
- Ran VBA code to completion, just on the off chance that it failed to clean something up when it errored out

It seems like PQ changed something outside of Office itself that keeps causing Excel to bomb out, but I can't imagine what or how. The Azure fix on the laptop suggests that it's Azure-related, but Excel still crashes even if the Azure add-in is disabled, or if it's in Safe Mode.